# find the probability (simple)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a set of marbles of which 4 are green and 15 are red, what is the probability of choosing a black one if I pick one at random?  I'm so confused!

Comment: OMG are you serious?

Answer (score 2):

The probability is zero or ${19 \choose 0}-1$..Since there is no black ball in our sample space..How could you take something if you don't have it?

Comment: Wow. Best answer for sure!